# How to find rows with only 8 numbers as value

Tags: postgresql

I want to find rows that not contains exactly 8 numbers in Ident column, everything non numeric, white space, less numbers, more numbers.. From column in PostgreSQL. From table below I want get everything without row ID 5

| ID | Ident |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FN033741 |
| 2 | NZ244/20 |
| 3 | 001091 |
| 4 | 01-09-16 |
| 5 | 06494824 |
| 6 | 102 |

I have tried this but don't know how to identified the rows with exactly 8 numbers.

where ident !~ '^[-+]?[0-9]*.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$'

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, I have tested it [here](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql-online.html):

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ident !~ '^\d{8}$';
```

- **^\d{8}$** is a regular expression that matches exactly 8 digits.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regular expression that matches anyy non-numeric characters and then count the number of numeric expressions. Applying this query might help:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE Ident ~ '^[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$' AND
      LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(Ident, '[^0-9]', '', 'g')) != 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this one

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE ident ~ '[^0-9]' OR
      (length(ident) <> 8 AND ident ~ '.*[0-9].*')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try out this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
WHERE Ident !~ '^[0-9]{8}$';
```